# D-dimensional multi-index sums

Tags: python, sum

I understand how a summation in 1, 2, and 3 dimensions could be defined by using 1, 2, and 3 `for` loops respectively, but how could you make a general function that sums over a multi-index like the one defined below?

[image]

Assume that `u` just samples a random integer for simplicity, i.e.,

```py
from random import randint
def u(a=0, b=100):
    return randint(a, b)
```

As an example, say the multi-index vector `js = [0, 0, 0]` and the upper limit vector `Ms = [5, 5, 5]`,this would imply that `d = 3` (i.e., 3 dimensional multi-index), and the summation could be written simply as below

```py
mysum = 0
for j1 in range(Ms[0]):
    for j2 in range(Ms[1]):
        for j3 in range(Ms[2]):
            mysum += u()
```

but what would be a general way to write this for `d` dimensions (like is shown in the image)?

Edit: I know in this trivial example, one could simply do something like

```py
from numpy import prod
M = prod(Ms)
mysum = sum([u() for i in range(M)])
```

but again, I am interested specifically in a sort of general way to do `d` nested `for` loops since the function `u` can be more complex and depend on the indices j_1, j_2, ..., j_d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to produce all the possible sets of indices to use in your function

```
mysum = 0
for indices in itertools.product(*[range(ms) for ms in Ms]):
    mysum += u()
```

`indices` will be

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 4)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform sums recursively: apply function `calculate_sum` to each element which is a list, returning sum of non-list elements:

```
def calculate_sum(lst):
    result = 0
    assert isinstance(lst, list), f"This is not a list: {lst}"
    for element in lst:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            result += calculate_sum(element)
        else:
            result += element
    return result

calculate_sum([[[0, -1, 7], [5, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]])
# > 49

calculate_sum([[0, -1, 7]])
# > 6

calculate_sum([5])
# > 5
```